# Isolation of parameter in co-dependent equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the two following equations :
$$T_i-T_{amb}=[T_{i-1}-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g}{h*A_s}]*e^{\frac{-h*A_s}{\rho*V*C_p}}+\frac{E_g}{h*A_s}$$
$$h=\frac{1}{0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i)}$$
I want to isolate $T_i$ in the first equation, but I'm having a hard time arriving at the right solution. The first step is to substitute $h$ in the first equation, but I'm not sure where to go from there.
$$T_i-T_{amb}=[T_{i-1}-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g}{\frac{A_s}{0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i)}}]*e^{\frac{-\frac{A_s}{0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i)}}{\rho*V*C_p}}+\frac{E_g}{\frac{A_s}{0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i)}}$$
Rewritten as
$$T_i-T_{amb}=[T_{i-1}-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g(0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i))}{A_s}]*e^{\frac{-A_s*\rho*V*C_p}{0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i)}}+\frac{E_g(0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i))}{A_s}$$

$$\frac{T_i-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g(0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i))}{A_s}}{T_{i-1}-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g(0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i))}{A_s}}=e^{\frac{-A_s*\rho*V*C_p}{0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i)}}$$

$$\ln{\frac{T_i-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g(0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i))}{A_s}}{T_{i-1}-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g(0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i))}{A_s}}}=\frac{-A_s*\rho*V*C_p}{0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i)}$$

$$\ln{[T_i-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g(0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i))}{A_s}]}-\ln{[T_{i-1}-T_{amb}-\frac{E_g(0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i))}{A_s}]}=\frac{-A_s*\rho*V*C_p}{0.125-(1.75*10^{-4}*T_i)}$$

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It would be very simple to isolate $T_{i-1}$. For $T_i$ ???

Comment: Yes, I already know $T_{i-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is doable but we can have a first *approximation* of $T_i$. This being more than likely a heat transfer problem, we can admit that $T_i$ is not very different from $T_{i-1}$

I shall first simplify the notations. Let
$$X_k=T_k-T_{\text{amb}}\qquad a=\frac {E_g}{A_s}\qquad b= -\frac{A_s}{\rho\,V\,C_p}$$ $$c=0.125 + d \,T_{\text{amb}} \qquad d=-1.75\times10^{-4}$$ to get
$$X_i=\Big[X_{i-1}-\frac a h\Big]\,e^{b\,h}+\frac a h\qquad \text{with} \qquad h=\frac 1{c+d\, X_i}$$
Now the idea is to use the first iteration of Newton method (or Taylor series limited to first order) or, if more accuracy is required, a full Newton method starting iterations at $X_{i-1}$.

If I am not mistaken, this would give
$$X_i\sim X_{i-1}+a\,d+e^{b h}\,\Bigg[1-d \Big[a+b h (h  X_{i-1}-1)\Big]\Bigg]$$ $h$ being computed at $X_{i-1}$.

Could you try and, please, let me know.